# Java Vaadin IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, vaadin

I use `vaadin` framework in Java. When I use `addComonent` to `Window(window.addComponent())`, program doesn't see method `addComponent`. What is problem?

Comment: When you hit Alt+Enter what options do appear? Also, when you hover over the red text what message does it show?

Comment: There is no red text.In code no problem, when I run the program in tomcat server java.lang.NoShuchMethodError: com.vaadin.ui.Window.setContent(Lcom/vaadin/ui/Component;)) like error

Comment: See answer below.. Btw, are you using this http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=6727 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the JAR via Project Structure settings ( tab Libraries ). If that doesn't help you try checking this step by step guide how to set up Vaadin with IDEA:

> 1) Download the Vaadin JAR
>
> 2) If not already done, install a Tomcat server
>
> 3) Start IntelliJ and create new project from scratch ( all steps below are performed with IntelliJ 9 )
>
> 4) Type of project is Java Module and as desired technology you select Web Application. This will create the web folder, including the WEB-INF dir and a web.xml file
>
> 5) Create a web/WEB-INF/lib folder and place the Vaadin JAR into that folder
>
> 6) Goto Project Structure | Modules and let your module depend on the Vaadin JAR. Mark it as export
>
> 7) Create a HelloWorld class and adjust your web.xml file, as described in the book of Vaadin
>
> 8) To run/debug, create a new "Tomcat Server" configuration. If not yet present, configure a Tomcat server by providing the link to the installation dir of your Tomcat server

Comment: in web browser error like this :HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.ui.Window.setContent(Lcom/vaadin/ui/Component;)V

Comment: setContent is defined like this: setContent(Component content) .. Why are you trying to set "Lcom/vaadin/ui/Component;" as a component for setContent method? what's that semicolon doing there for example? What's the "V"?

Comment: In the source code  no Letter "V"; my souce code is :package com;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleLoginView extends Application {
    @Override
    public void init() {
       Window main = new Window("My Vaadin Application");
       setMainWindow(main);
       VerticalLayout layout=new VerticalLayout();
       main.setContent(layout);
       layout.addComponent(new Label("Hello"));
    }
}

Comment: It looks like it's a problem specifically on your server. The answer which I provided was for general issues. I fear that I can't help you any any further. I will upvote your question at least